# Draw UIBeziperPath and get UIViews inside

Tags: uiview, drawing, line, uibezierpath

How I can know that UIViews are within the area of ​​a UIBezierPath? 
For example, I draw a line enclosing several points and want to know what of these points are inside.

The image shows what I mean ...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIBezierPath` has a method called `containsPoint` that can be used for this purpose.  You could, for example, check if the path contains the `center` point of the dot views.

Note however, `containsPoint` only works if the path is closed.  The path shown in the question would need to be closed at the top before `containsPoint` would work.

Comment: Thanks! I had not seen this method!